# Cannot run Docker Compose build

Tags: docker-compose

I clone the code from this repository https://github.com/ruoccofabrizio/azure-open-ai-embeddings-qna

I am trying to modify the code and rebuild the docker image using docker compose build, but nothing happen and the command end after 1 second.

When I run docker compose up, it seems to just load the old image and my changes is not shown in the web application. Even when I pulled the code and modify the code before running docker, my change is still not reflected on the web application.

I tried to build the image using docker-compose build --no-cache but it doesn't work also.

This is what it showed when I first run the application (docker compose up):

batch Pulling

web Pulling

api Pulling

f1f26f570256 Pulling fs layer

2d2b01660885 Pulling fs layer

4ea840b65f34 Pulling fs layer

bfa3763962ba Pulling fs layer

e76f10d4c3ff Pulling fs layer

3c98a0f1f4e2 Pulling fs layer

8e8f68274d4e Pulling fs layer

9ab5a5753089 Pulling fs layer

ebbcefe26604 Pulling fs layer

0825379af964 Pulling fs layer

1722a88500e6 Pulling fs layer

7cd88f631153 Pulling fs layer

a421b5c29c8e Pulling fs layer

9ab5a5753089 Waiting

1722a88500e6 Waiting

ebbcefe26604 Waiting

7cd88f631153 Waiting

.
.
.